# magento tier pricing

Tags: magento

In Magento, I have 4 customer groups setup, and different prices for each.

When I log in with a customer from one of these special groups, it shows the standard retail price of a product at $2.95 and a box beneath it that reads: 
   `Buy 6 for $2.49 each and save 16%`

I'm wondering if there is an easy way for it just to show the discounted price beside the retail price without all the rest of it.

I'm not sure where to start looking to make this modification...

**EDIT:** I'm running magento 1.5.0 - if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template change can be made at:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

or if you have local templates then in there.

Comment: What i'm seeing in there is calls to `$this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)` and `$this->getTierPriceHtml()` but it doesn't seem like this is the right place to make these changes... Where can i find the html generated by these functions?

Comment: try these files >>> /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml and /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml